# How to chain sorters with IEnumerable, with each sorter respecting the ordering produced by the previous one?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Basically, I have a small program where I'd like to perform a sequence of sorts on a list of objects. Each sort should operate on a different property of the object, and adhere to the ordering produced by the previous sort. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "John",   Age = 43 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Ringo",  Age = 73 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "John",   Age = 32 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Paul",   Age = 38 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "George", Age = 16 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "John",   Age = 80 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Ringo",  Age = 22 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Paul",   Age = 64 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "George", Age = 51 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "George", Age = 27 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Ringo",  Age = 5 });
        people.Add(new Person { Name = "Paul",   Age = 43 });

        Print(Sort(people));
    }

    static IEnumerable<Person> Sort(IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        //order by name first, then order by age
        return people.OrderBy(p => p.Name).OrderBy(p => p.Age);
    }

    static void Print(IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        foreach (Person p in people)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.Age);
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Ringo 5
George 16
Ringo 22
George 27
John 32
Paul 38
John 43
Paul 43
George 51
Paul 64
Ringo 73
John 80
```

But I'd like it to produce *this* output:

```
George 16
George 27
George 51
John 32
John 43
John 80
Paul 38
Paul 43
Paul 64
Ringo 5
Ringo 22
Ringo 73
```

In other words, I want it to order by `Name`, and then perform a localized ordering by `Age` within each `Name` "group". Obviously, the `Sort()` method I have so far doesn't do this, it just performs two chained `OrderBy`'s.

What's the best way I can do this with `IEnumerable`? Ideally, I'd like the solution to scale and support as many chained sorts as I want, each sort producing a set of "groups" that the next sorter must localize its sorting to.

Comment: Have you looked at ThenBy() to do the chaining?

Comment: You should definitely go with `ThenBy` as mentioned, but in case it is of interest: have you noticed how the two 43-year-olds are in alphabetical order? That could just be a coincidence, but it actually isn't. It's because `Enumerable.OrderBy` performs a stable sort, meaning any two records with the same age are sorted in the order they appeared in the underlying enumerable, which is ordered by name. This leads to an alternative solution: `.OrderBy(p => p.Age).OrderBy(p => p.Name)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using  it should reorder without breaking first order

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx

```
return people.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Age);
```

Comment: Way better suggestion than mine, which used string formatting.